# Hat "hau" als Begrüßung einen bestimmten Hintergrund?

Tags: etymology, reference-request

Ich hab grad keine Quelle, aber glaube es ist allgemein bekannt, dass "Hau!" im Kinderspiel als Indianergruß gilt. Im Duden steht es nicht.

**Wo kommt das her?**

Grimm kennt immerhin eine Interjektion im Oberdeutschen, “*sieh, schau*”, “er musz liegen: hau, so leugt er dann aus schwäbisch Indien. Fischart”(?) bzw. als lautmalend für Hundegebell mit *hahau* als Substantiv (DWB: [hau](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/hau)), das nichtsdestrotz zu *Hund* zu zählen sein dürfte, vgl. engl. *hound*.

Interessanter Weise ist doch lateinisch *ave* klassisch /ˈha.u̯e/ als Gruß ambivalent aus einer semitischen Wurzel einerseits (punish *ḥawe*, ḥ-w-y "live", en.Wiktionary, Thesaurus Linguae Latinae), doch andererseits aus *aveo* zu erklären (urindoeuropäisch **h₂ew-*, LIV *etc.*), welches mir [fragwürdig](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/46333/22504) erscheint (linguistics.SE “Welcome and bienvenidos”, *ad finis*).

Comment: Nur als *Gruß*? Ich meine, mich an Aussagen à la "Hau! Ich habe gesprochen!" zu erinnern, die auch in der Mitte einer Konversation stattfinden können.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Hau" dürfte eine verballhornte Version des klassischen "How", "Howgh" oder ähnlich sein. Das wiederum ist eine popkulturelle Anglisierung des Grußes [háu](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/h%C3%A1u) aus der Sprache [Lakota](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakota_(Sprache)). In den 1630ern von einem französischen Missionar (noch bei einem anderen indigenen Volk) beschrieben, wurden Varianten davon später Teil des stereotypen Bildes "des Indianers" bei Schriftstellern wie Karl May oder James Fenimore Cooper. Weitere Details gibt es bei Wikipedia ([deutsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howgh), [englisch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_(greeting))).

Comment: Karl May schrieb die Interjektion noch als "Hugh", was zu ziemlicher Verwirrung geführt hat.